# Using Facebook API, get list of user's groups where membership is pending approval

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

Using the Facebook API, it's possible to get retrieve a list of a user's groups if you have the user_groups permission. This only lists groups where the user is already a member. However, if a user asks to join a group, and am waiting approval by the admin, this group doesn't show up on the API's groups list.

Is there a way to see which groups the user has applied to, and is awaiting an administrator to approve membership?

Thanks. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can get group details and members list
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Answer (score 0):

From User table fields
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user
we can't see a "group_requests" or similar.

You may give a try to the 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/subscription
table, instead.

Answer (score 0):

No. The answer to the original question is no. This is not currently possible with the Facebook Groups API.